# Hyperlink issues on the #OculusGo and #OculusQuest when trying to "link" to a "heavy" scene

Tags: aframe, webvr, oculusgo

When using the OculusGO or the OculusQuest when you hyperlink from one virtual environment (VE) to another the Oculus Browser (and it also appears Firefox Reality last I checked) time-out. You go to the next scene; but are kicked out of VR which is undesirable.

Curious if anyone else has ran into this issue and if they were able to get around it, or perhaps have any ideas on how to get through it.

At this time it appears an issue in the WebVR implementation of events to control VR mode; but maybe there is a creative solution :)

I made a PR a little while ago ( https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4081 ) that did seem to work “most times” but there are some bizarre timing issues happening here (last I checked Mozilla Reality had the same behaviour).

Notes:
- It appears that there is a time-out happening that kicks the user out of something takes too long to load.
- I was under the impression that webVR will load things in asynchronously; so I am unsure how this time-outs. Perhaps I need more understanding here.

You can see a glitch here I created that highlights the problem by moving between a "light" and "heavy" scene: https://glitch.com/~portal-test-af-1

I also made a PR here that attempted to fix the problem ( https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4107 ); but, I assume due to some updates on Oculus's end, this "hack" no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and should be fixed here: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4199

Comment: Yes, thank you. This appears to have been resolved now.